# ColumnText.ShowTextAligned vs ColumnText.SetSimpleColumn Top Alignment

Tags: c#, itext

I'm having an issue understanding why when I set text using ColumnText.ShowTextAligned vs ColumnText.SetSimpleColumn and set the same Y coordinate they don't line up. Please see image below.

[image: Example]

The following code is used to add the Item Number, Estimated Qty and Description text:

```
// Item Number
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(item.ItemNumber.ToString(), fontQouteItems), 60, 450, 0);

// Estimated Qty
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(item.Quantity.ToString(), fontQouteItems), 143, 450, 0);

// Item Description
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas); // Uses a simple column box to provide proper text wrapping
ct.SetSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(193, 450, 390, 70));
ct.SetText(new Phrase(item.PDFDescription, fontQouteItems));
ct.Go();
```

I've omitted the code I don't think is relevant in order to simplicity the example.

I cannot figure out why when the Y coordinate for all 3 items set to 450 the one set using the ColumnText.SetSimpleColumn method is lower than the ones set using ColumnText.ShowTextAligned.

I've verified there is no new line at the beginning of item.PDFDescription.

Can anyone provide some insights as to what might be going on?

I can get it to line up by adding + 14 to the Y coordinate on the ColumnText.SetSimpleColumn however that is a hack and I would rather understand what is going on.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks as if `fontQuoteItems` starts with a `\n` character. Did you check what's inside `fontQuoteItems`?

Comment: @Bruno I just tested the code using constant strings without leading '\n', and I could reproduce the observation. I think, though, this difference is by design. The y coordinate parameter in `ColumnText.ShowTextAligned` is used as *baseline* while the upper y coordinate of the rectangle in `ct.SetSimpleColumn` is meant to be used as top of the area to fill.

Comment: Aha, yes, how could I overlook this? You are right, the `y` in `showTextAligned()` defines the baseline of the text. The `y` in `setSimpleColumn()` defines the top of the rectangle to fill.